# Split a string in JS by space having different length?

Tags: javascript

So I have following string I would like to split:

```
var str = 'Hello    How are you';
```

I want the result to look like:

```
['Hello','How','are','you'];
```

When I join it back it should be:

```
Hello, How are you
join(',')
```

A `,` should appear where length of space is more than 1. In our example it should be between `hello` and `How`.

Comment: The only way that you could have that *exact* array result, and be able to join it back the way you want, would be to join it based on words start with uppercase characters... do you think that would that work for your requirements? Of course, you could easily bypass the array all together and just do a replace... what is your actual goal here? Do you need the array for something, and if so does it need to be exactly that format?

Comment: So how the array should know that there were more than one space after certain element? The question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: @Vohuman: Yeah. The more I read the question, the less sense it makes to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. The only solution that I can think of is adding a helper property to the array object so we can know where the possible `,` should go after joining.

Comment: @Vohuman: That's what I thought of as well, *if* the OP really needs what it seems like they've asked for...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the result using **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** method. Replace all space length more than `1` with `,`.

```js
var str = 'Hello    How are you';
console.log(
  str.replace(/ {2,}/g, ', ')
)
```

Comment: hmmm... I would argue this is worse than T.J's... as you are assuming the only aim is the end result, and that the array isn't required for something else

Comment: @musefan: Frankly, I think the more constructive thing would be if you posted an answer addressing your understanding of the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Why... the question is not clear, I have commented to seek clarification, and *if* it arrives I may answer if somebody doesn't beat me too it. My only point is, at the moment any answer is just a guess... maybe OP will clarify and *this* will then be the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to *condense* all occurrences of a given character/string into a single one. I usually do the following, also use string.replace, like Pranav C. Balan, but with a different regex:

```js
var str = 'Hello    How are you';
var newStr = str.replace(/\s+/, ' ')
var strComponents = newStr.split(' ');

console.log(strComponents);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use split method:

```
var str = 'Hello    How are you';
var res = str.split(" ");
var array =[];
for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
   if(res[i] === ""){
      delete res[i];
    }else{
       array.push(res[i]);
    }
 }
 console.log(array)
```

Comment: Not actually what is wanted by the OP. Also, using `.filter` method is more suitable than looping throw all items.